# Movable object in a wxFrame

Tags: wxwidgets

I would like to draw an object(E.g Circle/Rectangle) on a wxFrame and have an event handler attached to each object such that onMouseDown, the object can be relocated to another position.

Currently, I'm not able to find any given samples or solution to go about this. I appreciate any help related to this problem.

Comment: that is probably because you are not supposed to draw directly onto the wxFrame object. you should draw onto a wxPanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned you shouldn't draw on a wxFrame. Instead you can use a wxPanel to draw your stuff. Here is a link with a
[drawing example](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Drawing_on_a_panel_with_a_DC)

Comment: Thanks for correcting me.
I'm able to draw multiple circle objects on the Panel but how can I access these objects drawn on the Panel so that I could tag an event handler to relocate its position when selected.

Comment: you attach an event handler to the panel and together with some bookkeeping (some container of your choosing containing the current size and position of your rectangle) you know which object is selected and move it according to the new mouse position

Comment: I have attached here, an event handler to the panel using this set of codes:

Panel1->Connect( wxID_ANY,
           wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN,
           wxMouseEventHandler(TestFrame::OnLeftDClick),NULL,this );

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: It seems like it. You should consider using a different overload of connect (one where you don't have to supply an wxID_Any) as it "could" produce  behavior you didn't want. or else you could use "Connect(Panel1->GetId(),wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN,wxMouseEventHandler(TestFrame::OnLeftDClick),NULL,this);

Comment: I'm able to get the handler to work but not the object to move its position upon mouseDown and mouseRelease to its new position.

Comment: as you get an "update" you need to set the new positions where to draw and then mark the panel as "dirty" so it gets redrawn